# How to flatten and group this HashMap, using streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given mapping of letters to numbers, I would like to return a list of Strings, where each String is a comma delimited list of the letters grouped by their associated number.

For this map

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    map.put("C", 4);
    map.put("D", 1);
    map.put("E", 1);
    map.put("F", 2);
```

I would like to return a List containing:

```
"A,D,E" "B,F", "C"
```

Any suggestions how this can be accomplished using the 1.8 streaming functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way doesn't reference `map` after it's initially streamed, and makes maximal use of the streaming facilities:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or more concisely, but with less usage of streams (thanks @Kartik):

```
return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values());
```

In either of those, if you add `TreeMap::new` as an argument between the two existing arguments to `Collectors.groupingBy`, the "inside" pieces will be sorted.

Comment: Ah, good use of `joining` in the `mapping` call. I like this one the best so far!

Comment: Could use list `List.copyOf` around the whole thing instead of `.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @flakes `List.copyOf` is new in Java 10, and I interpret the last sentence of the question to mean that answers need to work in Java 8.

Comment: Fair enough. Might be useful to future readers tho.

Comment: @JosephSible even in java 8, IntelliJ suggests to replace it with ArrayList constructor `new ArrayList<>(...)`

Comment: @Kartik Thanks, added.

Comment: this is great, thanks

Comment: @JosephSible any suggestions how i can modify this to sort the comma-delimited list? to guarantee the comma-delimited list of letters is in alphabetical order?

Comment: @ab11 Using the three-argument form of `groupingBy` and adding `TreeMap::new` as the new (second) argument should do that.

Comment: is there any advantage to `new ArrayList<>( ` or `collect` in terms of memory usage or speed?

Comment: @JosephSible thanks for all your help. but when I add `TreeMap::new` my results are still unsorted `        return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
                .values());`

Answer (score 2):

You can first group entries by value, and then use `Collectors.joining(",")`:

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .values().stream()
        .map(e -> e.stream()
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of `.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)`, use `.values.stream()`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I always make that mistake.. grr..

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt

```
List<String> results = map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.mapping(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.toList())))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(letters -> String.join(",", letters))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```