# How to sort this HashMap while flattening/grouping it, using streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I asked a question yesterday flattening/grouping a HashMap. I got a great response that suggested I do this.

```
return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values())
```

However, I would like my list of comma separated characters to be sorted alphabetically. The comments suggested I try using `TreeMap::new` as an argument to `groupingBy()`, but when I try this my list of characters remains unsorted:

```
return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values())
```

Below is my original question with a link to the post.

Given mapping of letters to numbers, I would like to return a list of Strings, where each String is a comma delimited list of the letters grouped by their associated number.

For this map

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    map.put("C", 4);
    map.put("D", 1);
    map.put("E", 1);
    map.put("F", 2);
```

I would like to return a List containing:

```
"A,D,E" "B,F", "C"
```

Any suggestions how this can be accomplished using the 1.8 streaming functions?

[How to flatten and group this HashMap, using streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055555/how-to-flatten-and-group-this-hashmap-using-streams/55055697?noredirect=1#comment96862085_55055697)

Comment: `TreeMap::new` would ensure the map is sorted based on natural ordering of keys which in your case is `Map.Entry::getValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the map to a `TreeMap` before performing the operation, and the keys will be in order in the output.

```
//                         * here
return new ArrayList<>(new TreeMap(map).entrySet().stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Map.Entry::getValue,
    TreeMap::new,
    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.joining(","))))
.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also work for you:

```
return new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), l -> {
                    Collections.sort(l);
                    return String.join(",", l);
                }))))
        .values());
```

Comment: Indeed that's the way to go ahead from the existing solution shared in the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking one of the answers to the linked question, this should do the trick for what you're looking for:

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .values().stream()
        .map(e -> e.stream()
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .sorted() // <<< modified this
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```